# Changing data schemas using Redis as a DB

Tags: redis

Currently Im working in a "eccomerce-like" application, more precisely a shopping cart + checkout application.

The team chooses Redis as our DB because performance is central to our delivery.

But, we are facing the problem of schema migrations. Se the example:

Lets suppose we have the following `CartItem` schema:

```js
class CartItem{
  id: UUID
  quantity: int
  prices: CartItemPrices
  stockInfo: CartItemStockInfo
}
```

Everything is fine but our stakeholders demanded that we implement a feature that needs a field `CartItem` field that segregates `CartItem.prices` attr in two new attributes:

```js
class CartItem{
  id: UUID
  quantity: int
  grossPrices: CartItemGrossPrices
  netPrices: CartItemNetPrices
  stockInfo: CartItemStockInfo
}
```

If we just deploy this code changes, our data will be in a wrong match with the actual entities in our Code, but just the old ones. New carts would be saved in the new shape. Old ones will broke when the API tries to access it, but new ones will work fine.

I if we were using a RDBMS, any popular library would provide us with a way to do "migrations". In this migration we would change the schemas in the tables and together with that we could run, in an automated way, a script that would convert the old data in the tables into the new data schema.

Is there a pattern or something the community does to solve this problem when using Redis as DB (instead of just cache storage)?

Comment: you never mentioned HOW the data is stored in redis - is it json? is it binary? is it in a set? a list? - the pattern is to run the migration yourself by writing code to update the old model to the new model

Comment: Each entity is stored using UUIDs as key, and the value stored are in JSON format. I imagined that write and run migrations manually was the right way to do it, but I was looking for ready-made solutions that facilitate this process, how django migrations work for RDBMS for example